# WCF service with WSDL disabled how to generate client and classes

Tags: c#, wcf, proxy, xsd, wsdl

I'm in trouble. We're working with another company and we need to consume a WCF service developped by them. The only thing i have in order to do the job is a integration document and XSD files from his service. I used xsd visual studio tool in order to generate the classes to consume with my proxy. I've been trying to make my own proxy class using HttpWebRequest but his serivice always responses errors with error 400 Bad Request.

Does anybody have a clue about make the job no so hard.

This is my code,  the object requ is of the type from classes generate by my xsd.

```
    public object Test(Testing.TestRequest requ)
{
    string responseFromServer;

    HttpWebRequest request = 
        (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://url.svc");

    request.Method = "POST";
        request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "MethodName");



        string xmlDocument = XmlSerialize<Testing.TestRequest>(requ);

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlDocument);

    request.ContentType = "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8";

        request.Accept = "text/xml";
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();

        return null;

}
```

Comment: In visual studio can you not just Add Service Reference - and paste in the url? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668183.aspx

Comment: No the wsdl is disabled.